# How to know which URL is being requested on AJAX function?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a `button` in which I call an AJAX function:

```
<button class="loadProduct" onclick="loadProduct(7)" type="button">Load product</button>
```

and this is my AJAX function:

```
var loadProduct = function (idProduct) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var product = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

            alert(product);

        }
        xhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost/product/loadProduct/" + idProduct, true);
        xhttp.send();
    };
};
```

in which it should send a request to the server and get the product but it does not show the alert.

I thought it was something related with the data response, but if I go directly to the link

```
http://localhost/product/loadProduct/7
```

I get the following response:

```
{"idProduct":"7","name":"product7"}
```

so I suspect that the AJAX function is not calling to this link because the response is being send correctly (if you access to it directly).

- How can I know if the AJAX function is calling to the correct link?
- Or is it an error with the AJAX function?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move your actual call outside of the `onreadystatechange` function:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    var product = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
  }
};
xhttp.open('GET', 'http://localhost/product/loadProduct/' + 1, true);
xhttp.send();
```

Comment: You are the best! Thank you very much! What a mistake!

Answer (score 2):

Just open the console and check the request...

Comment: It is not being shown any AJAX call or maybe I am searching in the wrong place. I am using Google Chrome and go to Network tab.

Comment: Most browsers has a developer console you can use to see these thing. Here is Mozilla Firefoxs: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)